# how to update and delete data in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm doing CRUD in DRF and 2 operations(Get, Post) are working fine but got an error in PUT and DELETE operation. Put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' and same error for delete. delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id', and when i try to get data by passing id in url i got this error "get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'"

i changed url pattern but getting the same error

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import Employee
from .serializer import EmployeeSerializer

class employeeList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        employee1 = Employee.objects.all()
        serializer1 = EmployeeSerializer(employee1 , many = True)
        return Response(serializer1.data)

    def post(self, request):
        employee1 = request.data.get("")
        serializer1 = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data, 
partial=True)
        if serializer1.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            employee_saved = serializer1.save()
        return Response({"success": "Employee '{}' created 
successfully".format(employee_saved.first_name)})
    def put(self , request, id):
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id)
        data = request.data.get("")
        serializer1 = EmployeeSerializer(instance = employee , 
data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer1.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            saved_employee = serializer1.save()
        return Response({"success":"Employee '{}' updated 
successfully".format(saved_employee.first_name)})
    def delete(self, request, id):
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id)
        employee.delete()
        return Response({"message":"Employee '{}' deleted 
successfully".format(employee.first_name)}, status=204)
```

> serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Employee.objects.create(**validated_data)
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

instance.first_name=validated_data.get('first_name',instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = 
validated_data.get('last_name',instance.last_name)
        instance.employee_id = 
validated_data.get('employee_id',instance.employee_id)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from webapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^employee/', views.employeeList.as_view()),
    url(r'^employees/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.employeeList.as_view())
]
```

i expect to see the success message but i get error message

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate the method each url pattern is going to manage:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from webapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^employee/', views.employeeList.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post': 'create'})),
    url(r'^employees/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.employeeList.as_view({'get': 'retrieve', 'put': 'update', 'delete': 'destroy'}))
]
```

`'get': 'list'` indicates that method GET is going to be managed by class method `list()` of the view.

Comment: i changed url patterns but now i am getting this error. as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given